# Wallet.rs: ValueError: error accessing storage: IO error: lock hold by current process [...}: No locks available

Tags: python, shimmer, wallet.rs

Sending native tokens SMR with Shimmer's wallet.rs in existing Python output the following error:

`ValueError: error accessing storage: IO error: lock hold by current process, acquire time 1675876083 acquiring thread 2310207: ./alice-database/LOCK: No locks available`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the code was setting up the [account manger](https://wiki.iota.org/shimmer/wallet.rs/how_tos/accounts_and_addresses/create_a_wallet_account/) twice.

`wallet = IotaWallet('./alice-database', client_options, coin_type, secret_manager)`

It was resolved by setting up the account manager only once.